# Doctrine - ManyToOne where the One is not an id, but a relationship (oneToOne)

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a certain database Entity mapping in PHP defined with Doctrine ORM attributes.
From [the reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/attributes-reference.html) I've understood, that to define a **ManyToOne** relation (not <del>ManyToMany</del>, NOT <del>oneToMany</del>), one can have following defined on their entity:

```
    // Borrow.php
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Book::class, fetch: "LAZY")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'publication_id', referencedColumnName: 'publication_id')]
    private Book $book;
```

This would most likely work fine, if the `Book` had primary key of its own, like `book_id`, but it doesn't and I can't really do nothing about that, instead, it is actually related to a generic `Publication` with one to one relationship:

```
    // Book.php
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: Publication::class)]
    #[JoinColumn(name: 'publication_id', referencedColumnName: 'publication_id')]
    private Publication $publication;
```

So what I end up getting is a following error:

`Cannot assign int to property App\Entity\Book::$book of type App\Entity\Publication`

Is it necessary to define a helper `$bookId` property on the `Book` (and dupe-map it to `publication_id`) or something similar

or are there some options I don't know about to handle cases like this one?

Thanks.

EDIT: To be clear, if I would ***remove*** the one-to-one relationship field in `Book` and replaced it with following, it would work:

```
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'publication_id', type: 'integer', options: ['unsigned' => true])]
    private int $bookId;
```

And it also seems to work, if I use both, but use `#[ORM\Id]` only for the `int $bookId`, not for the `Book $book`.

Comment: When is the error thrown exactly?

Comment: when calling something like `$myBorrow->getBook();` (which just gives `$this->book`) (or maybe even on the very app load, not sure now)

Comment: I just realized the error says `App\Entity\Book::$book` and not `App\Entity\Borrow::$book`, why does you Book entity have a $book property? And why is its type `App\Entity\Publication`?

Comment: that may have been a mistake - it may have been Book::$publication and I have a feeling it was